# Excel Pivot Sub total columns

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that has the following structure:

Row labels: - Order ID
Column labels: - Customer Type
Values: - Sum

I have the following customer types:

- Business_S
- Business_M
- Business_L
- Private_S
- Private_M
- Private_L

Now I want a sub total column that adds up the total sum for the three Business columns and the three Private columns respectively.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a new column in your source data. Perhaps, `Business Type` and label it accordingly.  Then just rearrange the pivot table as you see fit.

[image: Table]
[image: Pivot]
[image: Pivot List]

Comment: That was my fear as well, I can do it but hoped there was another way of doing it. Thanks for your answer though, even if it's "bad News"

Comment: Should be pretty easy to do this with formulas. Use something like: `LEFT(A1, FIND("_",A1)-1)`

Comment: I just realized that the same Thing you described for rows does not work as easily for columns, I will have to go back to the drawing board and find another solution. This one works for rows but for columns (I actually have 3 field as column Labels) it doesnt work